# Restricting the ability to reassign tasks in Camunda tasklist

Tags: camunda, camunda-modeler

I have defined an assignee for a user task. According to the official Camunda 8 docs, the section on [User tasks access restrictions](https://docs.camunda.io/docs/self-managed/tasklist-deployment/tasklist-authentication/?authentication=identity&_gl=1*1j59t0y*_ga*NTQyOTMyMTg3LjE2ODM1MjQxOTA.*_ga_4EYN8X5FNR*MTcwNjQzNzIwMi4yMS4xLjE3MDY0NDI0MzQuNDkuMC4w#user-task-access-restrictions), tasks can be prevented from being visible for other people who are not assigned to the task. In other words, when we assign a user task to a specific user by their username (defined in an IAM service like Keycloak), others cannot see or reassign the task.
However, even if I define an assignee for my user task, all the people who have access to the tasklist can reassign the task and complete it. How can I prevent it?

PS: I have tried setting `USER_RESTRICTIONS_ENABLED` environment variable to `true` in Identity component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like adding an environment variable called `USER_RESTRICTIONS_ENABLED` takes effect after a while. It worked! You can take a look at the full thread on the Camunda forum [here](https://forum.camunda.io/t/restricting-the-ability-to-reassign-tasks-in-tasklist/50194/3).